# In Jenkins, how do I get the substring of a build parameter to be part of the build name?

Tags: jenkins

I've got a parameterized freestyle Jenkins job, and I'd like to include part of one of the parameters in the build name. The parameter that I'm interested in is called `FILE_PATH`. Due to the file directory structure of the project used by this job, the file path always starts with the same string, which is 9 characters long. So if `FILE_PATH="somepath/what/I/want"`, I would like the name of my build to be `what/I/want`.

Some things I've tried putting in the "Set Build Name" field provided by the Build Name Setter plugin:

#### `${FILE_PATH:9}`

This gave me the following error:

```
Failed to evaluate name macro:org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'FILE_PATH' in '${FILE_PATH:9}'
```

#### `${"FILE_PATH":9}`

FILE_PATH was just treated as a string:

```
New run name is '${"FILE_PATH":9}'
```

#### `${$FILE_PATH:9}`

This just led to the raw expression being included with `FILE_PATH` being expanded:

```
New run name is '${somepath/what/I/want:9}'
```

#### `${ENV,var="FILE_PATH":9}`

This didn't get processed at all:

```
New run name is '${ENV,var="FILE_PATH":9}'
```

I've got the [Build Name Setter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/) and the [Token Macro](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/) plugins installed. I'd like to do this in the Build Name plugin, if possible, although I *can* install any other plugins I need to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${ENV:9,var="FILE_PATH"}` should do what you are looking for.

An alternative is to also eliminate the beginning of the string, as far as you know what exactly the string is:

```
${ENV#somepath/,var="FILE_PATH"}
```

In case you ever need to strip something from the end of the string instead, use `%` in place of `#`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a Jenkinsfile pipeline script?
If so, you can just use the groovy substring method.

```
variable.substring(9)
```

Not sure if you can do something similar using parameterized builds.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a freestyle job. I'll update my question.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult in a freestyle job. You can probably try using a groovy build step and then envinject? I find when you need to start doing a lot of custom things in Jenkins though it is super beneficial to upgrade to pipeline/Jenkinsfile. It adds a lot more flexibility.